# N1 series instance on GCP no longer supporting virtualisation/KVM for Eve-NG-Pro

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, kvm

I have had an N1 series instance running in GCP since last July which was configured with a boot disk configured for nested virtualisation. It hasn't been used for sometime but having launched it this week I have discovered that KVM is no longer supported,

kvm-ok gives me the results below
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used

grep -cw vmx /proc/cpuinfo results in 0 (Which I understands to mean Nested virtualisation is enabled)

The fault manifests when using QEMU images within Eve-NG-Pro which briefly try to start then immediately drop back to off/down status. Docker based images still work.

Has something changed within GCP recently that means what I am doing no longer works or am I missing something obvious?

I investigated as best I could then finally gave up and decided to create a new VM following the procedure I believe to be correct but ultimately found this failed also. I have also tried N2 with Intel Cascade Lake CPU platforms with no success.

Appreciate any ideas

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, I have been away.
I have now changed to Intel Haswell processor and all is running as before. Honestly not sure what changed as this was working fine for 6 months plus but all good now, thanks for the suggestion, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the VM to use an Intel Haswell processor.

[Specifying a minimum CPU platform for VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform)

[About nested virtualization](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/overview)